# NanoHTTPD 2.0.5 issue with file upload with spaces in filename

Tags: android, nanohttpd

I have an android app that uses NanoHTTPD to serve HTML context.
I'm using **NanoHTTP 2.0.5** in my App.

There's a problem with file uploads.
Suppose I upload a file named **kr d.mp4**; it gets uploaded but renamed to **k** (starting from one character before space till last char in filename including extension is removed).

Any file upload that has **space** shows this behaviour.
I tried other file name :

```
 ORIGINAL         GOT THIS
-----------------------------
NO_SPACE.TXT      NO_SPACE.TXT  (works as expected)
ABC DEF.txt       AB
AB1234 gf.txt     AB123
A D.txt           Failed to upload ???
```

How do I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with help from IRC channel **#android-dev** by user : **memoryleak**. It was an encoding related issue.

To fix it do this when uploading on :

**Client side (Javascript) :**

```
formdata.append("filedata", file, encodeURIComponent(file['name']));
```

**Server Side (NanoHTTPD) :**

```
URLDecoder.decode(session.getParms().get(entry.getKey()), "UTF-8");
```